# How to show sections in mobile mode like desktop mode?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page that contains some images and texts positions next to each other.In desktop mode everything is fine but in mobile mode (Responsive mode) all sections that contain images and texts have no correct order (i want to be exactly like desktop mode order) how can i fix this problem.i tried `order` property but problem not solved.

Website: http://titanotrade.com.tr/service.html

Comment: what elements do not have correct order? Do you want to have image and text on the side on mobile as well?

Comment: no in desktop i want to have image and text on the side but in mobile related image and text under each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap you can reverse the cols of a row. Even in responsive variations too.

0. Delete the `.services-grid .resposive-content` and `.services-grid .resposive-image` rules from your css. You don't need them.
1. Wrap every two col elements into row a parent.
2. Make the order of the text and image to represent the order on mobile.
3. Use the `flex-lg-row-reverse` class on the rows that have to reverse the col positions.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6>image</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6>text</div>
</div>
<div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse">
    <div class="col-lg-6>image</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6>text</div>
</div>
```

On desktop view (larger than lg), the `flex-lg-row-reverse` class will swap the image and the text.

```
Mobile        Desktop
- image       image - text
- text        text  - image
- image
- text
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Bootstrap v4.
You need to add the breakpoints for the mobile version.

div class="col-6"
div class="col-6"

to keep photo - text in mobile <576px

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

Regards.

Comment: i don't understand...I would appreciate it if you Writing  exact code or exact place of code

Comment: This is not what the op is asking for. There are breakpoints already.